# CoreLocation Negative Values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

I am using the `CoreLocation` framework to get my speed and distance to calculate average speed.

On the first update that `CoreLocation` sends out, it shows negative values for both speed and distance traveled. How can I fix this?

Speed is `locationController.locationManager.location.speed` where `locationController` holds my `CoreLocation` delegate. Distance is calculated by taking the old location and the new location and calculating distance.

```
//Distance
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // make sure the old and new coordinates are different
    if ((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude) &&
        (oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))
    {         
        mDistance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data returned by Core Location may be invalid for a number of reasons. Before you use the data, run this method to see if it is valid.

```
// From http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/02/detecting-bad-corelocation-data/
- (BOOL)isValidLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
        withOldLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    // filter out nil locations
    if (!newLocation){
        return NO;
    }
    // filter out points by invalid accuracy
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0){
        return NO;
    }
    // filter out points that are out of order
    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastPoint = [newLocation.timestamp 
                                            timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
    if (secondsSinceLastPoint < 0){
        return NO;
    }
    // filter out points created before the manager was initialized
    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceManagerStarted = [newLocation.timestamp 
                                                 timeIntervalSinceDate:locationManagerStartDate];
    if (secondsSinceManagerStarted < 0){
        return NO;
    }
    // newLocation is good to use
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This works well, but I also had to add something to prevent the negative distance: `if ([newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation] <0)
    {
        return NO;
    }`

Comment: Sorry, I got it from my snippets app and didn't have an URL at the time. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

There's a note in the [`CLLocationManager` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html):

> Because it can take several seconds to return an initial location, the location manager typically delivers the previously cached location data immediately and then delivers more up-to-date location data as it becomes available. Therefore it is always a good idea to check the timestamp of any location object before taking any actions.

You should check whether you're getting a cached value and ignore it, waiting for the first "real" update.

```
NSTimeInterval timeSinceLastUpdate = [[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];

// If the information is older than a minute, or two minutes, or whatever
// you want based on expected average speed and desired accuracy, 
// don't use it.
if( timeSinceLastUpdate < -60 ){
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are collecting the first point, it has no reference to calculate speed or distance. I believe it is defined to return -1 if it can't get you what you need.

To resolve this, simply check for the negative values.

```
if(location.speed > 0) {
    return;
}
```