# Distance between CLLocations won't return correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocationdistance

In my app, I'm trying to get the distance between two locations. I pressed my app's button, walked across the (big) room, and the CLLocationDistance returned as 0.000000.

.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *stopButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *firstLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *secondLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    self.firstLocation = [self deviceLocation];
}

- myButtonFunction {
    self.secondLocation = [self deviceLocation];
    self.locationLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", [self.firstLocation distanceFromLocation:self.secondLocation]];
}

- (CLLocation *)deviceLocation {
    return [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Comment: Your room is a hundred meters wide?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Sorry, that was some old code, I re-did it with kCLLocationAccuracyBest and it still didn't work

Comment: you have to implement of the CLLocationManagerDelegate methods delegate. When the location manager detects a location change, it calls the didUpdateToLocation delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the location manager tells you that it has new information. Until that happens, you'll just get the same location all the time.

The manager will inform you via the delegate method [`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW16)  (`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` for iOS < 6.0). You need a class that implements that method to be assigned as the location manager's delegate, and you can't check the new location until that method is called.

Also, be aware that the first time that method is called, there might not actually be *fresh* data. See [my answer at "Core Location Negative Values"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970780/603977).

Comment: Can I force the CLLocationManager to give me new data? (force the method)

Comment: Nope. Also, be aware of this: [CoreLocation negative values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7970780/603977)

Comment: I was just looking at the documentation, wouldn't CLLocationManager's startUpdatingLocation function work in this situation?

Comment: And @JoshCaswell I don't think that's it either, I waited about a minute in each end of the room before pressing the button.

Comment: `startUpdatingLocation` makes the manager start updating. _Once it has updated_, it calls that method to let you know. You have to wait.

Comment: It takes longer than a minute?

Comment: It might take longer than a minute, yes.

Comment: That can't be right- for example, in the maps app, if you're driving or running, you can see your location update every few seconds as you move. How do they do it that's different from my method?

Comment: It might take a while _the first time_. Try my suggestion, and report back _if it doesn't actually work_.

Comment: It didn't work the first time I tried, which is pretty much why I originally replied

Answer (score 0):

By using the device location you lose a lot of control over what is actually being recorded.  For example, the device location could have conditions where it does not update unless your location changes by more than 20 meters...   Or perhaps it updates once an hour.  You have no way to know.

As Josh was saying you have to get locations from the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` callback(s).  Store them in your class, and when your buttons are hit record the last location you stored.  Only then will you get data related to the location settings you have specified.